# How is a vertical electric field polarized through a rotated polarizer?

Tags: waves, electric-fields, polarization

If you have, for example, an electric field in the vertical direction ($\hat{y}$ component) and it passes through a polarizer that is angled at $\theta$, what components of the electric field are parallel to the polarizer axis that it is being passed through?

I understand if you have instead an angled electric field or light source, and it is passed through a vertical polarizer, the y component of the wave will pass through, resulting in a smaller amplitude and as a result a lower intensity. But I don't understand how the above example would work.

Comment: It's the exact same situation, but rotated.

Comment: Ah ok I see. So the y component of the transmitted wave is parallel with the y component of the polarizer. Thanks!